# Constant pointer array with struct fields that may point to malloc allocated fields?

Tags: c

```
int main() {    
    Employee *array[SIZE]; //Employee is a typedef struct --includes char *name, DATE *dateOfBirth, DATE is also a typedef struct, has 3 int fields month, day, year,`  

fillArray(array, &count, fpin1, fpin2);

freeMemory(array, int count);

}  

fillArray(Employee *array[], int *count,  FILE *fpin1, FILE *fpin2)  
    char buffer[MAX], buffer2[MAX];  
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fpin1) != NULL && fgets(buffer2, MAX, fpin2) != NULL){  
        array[*count]->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*25);  
        assert(array[*count]->name != NULL);  
        strncpy(array[*count]->name, buffer, 15);  

        strncpy(buffer2, temp, 2);
        array[*count]->dateOfBirth->day = atoi(temp)
}
```

The code compiles but keeps failing with segmentation fault, it seems to fail at my fgets? or my malloc, what am I doing wrong? I really can't seem to figure that out.

Also how would you go about freeing this memory in a

```
freeMemory(Employee *array[], int count)
```

function?

Comment: I'd suggest separating `malloc` and assignment. Both can cause a `segfault` as you have an array access in the same line. Also why not put some `printf`s here and there for the purpose of debugging?

Comment: Have a ton of printf statements all over it, but I am still stuck so hard...it seams to die after the  while--which doesn't make sense since it just a fgets function, and if I some how manage to get it past that it seg faults after the malloc. If I comment out the malloc and just let it do something simple (put a int into a field of the struct) it ends up going though the files and then segfaults again.

Comment: 'count ' is an int defined in main, passed to fillarray as a pointer so it can be increment to show the number of employees, and then used to create the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
int main() {    
    Employee array[SIZE]; //Employee is a typedef struct --includes char *name, DATE *dateOfBirth, DATE is also a typedef struct, has 3 int fields month, day, year,`  

fillArray(&array, &count, fpin1, fpin2);

freeMemory(&array, int count);

}
```

You aren't allocating your `Employee` objects anywhere, so array[0] points to some random address.

Comment: doesn't Employee array[SIZE]; allocate memory on compile time? `#define SIZE 25`  by the way

Comment: @Wilson11: It allocates an array of `SIZE` pointers to `Employee`.  It does not allocate `SIZE` structures.  Also, you probably want the `dateOfBirth` member of the structure to just be a `DATE` instead of a pointer to `DATE`, since it's a fixed size and you don't want to have to allocate it for every element.

Comment: How can I allocate memory for it since, it is a constant pointer and I can't touch the main method, or the .h file that has the struct definitions.

Comment: @Wilson11: You'll have to malloc it as well.  Look at @Muggen's code to see how you can malloc the `Employee` struct, then malloc space for the `name` and `dateOfBirth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee* array[SIZE];
```

This is an array that stores pointers to `Employee` structs.

I think you mean

```
fillArray(Employee* array[], int* count,  FILE *fpin1, FILE *fpin2)
{
    char buffer[MAX], buffer2[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    while ( fgets(buffer, MAX, fpin1) != NULL && 
            fgets(buffer2, MAX, fpin2) != NULL )
    {
        // the array does not hold any valid memory address.
        array[i] = malloc( sizeof(Employee) );
        assert( array[i] != NULL );

        // now on the new employee add some char memory
        (array[i])->name = malloc( sizeof(char) * 25 );
        assert(array[i]->name != NULL);

        strncpy(array[i]->name, buffer, 15);
        strncpy(buffer2, temp, 2);

        array[i]->dateOfBirth->day = atoi(temp)

        ++i;
        (*count)++; 
    }  
}
```

doing `array[*count]` besides looking weird, always modifies the same index. You never modified `*count` anywhere.

This code does not check that you do not exceed the bounds of the `array` passed.

Also : for the `freeMemory()`

```
freeMemory(Employee* array[], int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( i < count )
    {
        free(array[i]);
        array[i] = NULL;
        ++i;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You forgot to malloc `dateOfBirth`, and the `freeMemory()` function needs to free both `array[i]->dateOfBirth` and `array[i]->name` before it frees `array[i]`.

Comment: @tomlogic, oops thats correct. But now I think OP will see the logic.